# Evaluate $\ \int_0^3 x^3\,d[\frac{x}{2}]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I know the result must be $1,$ I also know that:

$ n\leq x/2 < n+1 \Leftrightarrow$
$ 2n \leq x < 2n+2$

For $n=0$ we have that

$ 0 \leq x <2 $

$ 0\leq x/2 <1 \Rightarrow$
$ [x/2] = 0$

Similarly, for $n=1,$ $ [x/2] = 1$

How can I use these facts to evaluate the integral?

Comment: I think the answer is $2^3$

Comment: Integration by parts quickly gives the answer $3^3 - (3^3 - 2^3) = 2^3$, but perhaps that's "cheating"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if $f(x)=\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{2}\right\rfloor\!,$ then it's easier to work, on your domain, with $f(x)=U(x-2),$ the unit step function. Then  $f'(x)=U'(x-2)=\delta(x-2)$ on your domain. You could use the identity $\int_a^b f(x)\,\delta(x-c)\,dx=f(c)$ if $a<c<b$.

Comment: Writing $\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$ in terms of the unit step function shows that the derivative is $\delta(x-2)$, giving $\int_0^3 x^3 \delta(x-2) dx = 8$. Using this formalism is slightly tricky when there are discontinuities at the endpoints; $\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$ is continuous from the right at $x=0$, therefore the $\delta(x)$ term shouldn't be included.

Comment: @Maxim: good point. I'll edit.

Comment: Why $1/2$ though, it's just $\delta(x-2)$. The coefficient at $\delta$ is the size of the jump.

Comment: Don't you need to use the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, but that would essentially give $(H(x/2))' = 1/2\delta(x/2) = \delta(x)$. It's easier to just work with $H(x-2)$.

Comment: Ah, good. I'll edit again!

Comment: I'm really lost at how I can get the result using this

Comment: Let $u=\lfloor x/2\rfloor$. Then $du=d\lfloor x/2\rfloor = (\lfloor x/2\rfloor)'\,dx.$ But in my answer, you have that, on your domain, $\lfloor x/2\rfloor=U(x-2)$. So now you have $du=H'(x-2)\,dx=\delta(x-2)\,dx$. So your integral becomes $\int_0^3 x^3\,\delta(x-2)\,dx$. Now use the Dirac delta property to evaluate this integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the Riemann-Stieltjes sum
$$ S_n = x_1^3([x_1/2]-[x_0/2])+\dots+x_i^3([x_i/2]-[x_{i-1}/2])+x_{i+1}^3([x_{i+1}/2]-[x_i/2])+\dots+x_n^3([x_n/2]-[x_{n-1}/2]) $$
Then we choose $i$ so that $x_{i-1}/2<1<x_{i+1}/2$, most terms will cancel out, and we will have
$$ S_n =x_i^3([x_i/2]-[x_{i-1}/2])+x_{i+1}^3([x_{i+1}/2]-[x_i/2])= (x_i^3-x_{i+1}^3)[x_i/2]+x_{i+1}^3 $$
And by taking a limit
$$ S_n \to 2^3 $$
So from the definition $$\int_0^3 x^3 \,\text{d}[\frac{x}{2}] = 2^3 $$